# Do stuff after login/logout in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm a newbie in Laravel framework

I faced a problem when implementing auth in Laravel 5.2. So i used the `make:auth`of Laravel 5.2 to create a simple login/register/logout mechanism, but i want to do something after login/logout (more specific is i want to send a `$request` base on `username` and `password` (access token)). My problem is Laravel 5.2 make all the authentication encapsulated in `Route::auth();` so i don't know where to put my code to, i tried to put the code in `AutheticatesUsers.php` file, my supervisor said to me i shouldn't put the code in the core file of Laravel because it can change when the framework update. So where i can put the code to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you thought making a manual `authentication`?

Comment: Yeah but can i making modification about laravel authentication, cause my supervisor want me to use that! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 5.2, you can override auth methods in `AuthController.php`(allow you custom laravel `auth`) that is `login`, `logout`, `register`... if you want do something after authenticating just override method `authenticated`.

Comment: and where should i override those method? Thanks

Comment: `root/http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` the default method in `AuthenticatesUsers.php`